# Probability, question involving a random event, then the assumption of a specific event

Tags: probability

I have this question that I'm having serious problem with. I think there is something wrong with the question it self but I'm not exactly sure what it is. If the question is indeed valid, please help me with getting the answer, thanks.

There are 4 cards, denote by A,B,C,D

You now shuffle these 4 cards and randomly pick 2 cards from these 4. If you have A, what is the probability that you have B as well?

My problem is this: If I draw one card at a time, I see that the first card is A, then the chance that the second card is B surely is 1/3. Here, the drawing of the second card has not happened yet and is entirely random.

(I assume that randomness applies only to events that has not happened yet. If an event happened already, then all there is left is the act of revealing, which is not random.)

But If I draw 2 cards at once ( without order ), then assume one of the cards is A, then this places the act of drawing the 2 cards in the "already happened" state.And there is nothing random about revealing what has already happened since the result is already there. So there is no randomness about the second card picked.

Thanks

Comment: Do you understand conditional probability?

Comment: I meant before you draw the 2 cards, it is still random, once you drew the two cards, it has already happened and there is no more randomness. The act of assuming one of the cards to be A is to assume that the drawing has already happened, which makes it non-random now.

Comment: Let me see if I can explain it. Suppose you play a game that involves drawing 2 cards out of 4. The first card is drawn. You are told that it is A. Now, what is the probability of drawing B as the second card?

Comment: I have no problem with this, since I am drawing the cards one at a time, the only problem I have is when I draw two cards at once ( no first and second )

Comment: OK, now suppose you draw 2 cards at once. You open one of the cards. You find that it is A. Now, what is the probability that the other card is B?

Comment: Thank you, this is my precise problem. I can not answer this because I've already drawn them, there is no randomness anymore.     If the question is, if I draw 2 cards at once, what is the chance that I will get A and B, then its 1/6, since I have not drawn yet, so its still random

Comment: randomness simply means that you do not know with certainty what the value is going to be. It has nothing to do with whether you have or haven't drawn the card. So, in this case, it still applies because you cannot be certain that the card is B. All you can do is guess and you have a 1 in 3 chance of guessing right.

Comment: That makes sense but the question is asking for the chance of the card being something, not what I would guess, off course me guessing is still random.

Comment: The point is that if you have to guess, that means it's still random to you because you are uncertain about what it will be.

Comment: Yes but im not guessing, Im asked for the chance that the card will be B, but the card I drew is already there, it is what it is.       I think I will just drop it, though I appreciate your timely responses :D thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of focusing on **randomness**, lets think about it in terms of **known** and **unknown**.

So you've drawn two cards from the deck. At that point both cards are **unknown**. And @DSinghvi's answer is correct. The probability of drawing an A and a B is 1/6, i.e. $P(A\: and \:B) = \frac16$

Then you are told that one of the cards is A. So now you **know** one card is A and the other card is still **unknown**. You will no longer be calculating $P(A\: and \:B)$, you will be calculating $P(B\:| \:A) = \frac13$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, so you are saying this is the same as my first version, you pick a card first, see its A, then you pick a second card. But at this point, picking the second card is random. For your version, the card is already there, I am the one who doesn't know the result so I have a 1/3 chance of guessing it right, not that theres a 1/3 chance that the second card is B. but thats not the same as what the question is saying though. Is it? totally confused

Comment: Another way I can think of your version is that the only way the second card is B is if I choose A and B when I drew, which has a chance of 1/6, and revealing one of them shouldn't change the chance... or does it...

Comment: The *a priori* or *prior* probability of choosing A and B is 1/6 and that never changes. But once you **know** some of the information, you have now have the *posterior* probability of $P(B\:|\:A)$. Take a look a Bayesian probability http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability That might help clear things up.

Comment: Think about it this way. If you know you have A, then a probability of 1/6 implies that you might not have an A!. Since you do have an A... you could only have: AB, AC, or AD.

Comment: I think the question is trying to trick you!